# How to use loop using this syntax?

Tags: android

```
//Priority checkbox    
q1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.q1a); 

//"Sub" checkboxes
q2 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.q2a); 
q3 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.q3a);
q4 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.q4a);
q5 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.q5a);


if q1 is checked and 2 or more of the "sub" checkboxes are checked then{
new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(R.string.positive).show(); 
}
```

Can someone help me to code this syntax using a loop in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to store those checkboxes in some sort of array / list to be able to iterate through them with a loop. Here's a possible solution:

```
q1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.q1a);    

ArrayList<CheckBox> cbList = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
cbList.add((CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.q2a)); 
cbList.add((CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.q3a));
cbList.add((CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.q4a));
cbList.add((CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.q5a));

if (q1.isChecked()){
    int count = 0;
    for (CheckBox cb : cbList) {
        if (cb.isChecked()) {
           count ++;
        }
    }
    if (count >= 2){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(R.string.positive).show(); 
    }
}
```

Also note that `setMessage(R.string.positive)` is probably not what you are trying to achieve, as this will only set the message to a number generated in R (and will probably give you an error expecting you to input a String). You would in fact have that line as:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(getString(R.string.positive)).show();
```

**EDIT:** The alternative requested in the comment would be something like:

```
for (CheckBox cb : cbList) {
    if (cb.isChecked()) {
       count ++;
    }
}

if (q1.isChecked() || count >= 2){
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(R.string.positive).show();
}
```

Note that no optimizations have been attempted.

Comment: can i put esle there..if only q1 or any of the sub checkboxes (1 or 2 or more) is checked the result is setMessage(R.string.negative) @Vlad

Comment: I have edited the post to work with your latest question. I am not sure if you want it to validate if ANY of the 2 conditions are true, BOTH are true or ONLY ONE is true ...

Answer (score 0):

Make a seperate function that sets a global variable to true if two or more checkboxes is checked.

Use the eventhandler of each checkbox.